# 2 INNER JOIN For 2 colums that use the same foreign key

Tags: php, html, sql, database, inner-join

First, I have my database like this:

[image: My Database]

And the relations:

[image: Relations]

And now in the .php I want to create the table that shows everything in the table but instead of showing ProductId and UpgradeProductId as a number, I want to show them as name of the product

The problem is how can I do it? I already made this

[image: My SQL Connection]

And it show up like this

[image: Table]

I want the [UpgradeProductId] to come out as Product Name like [ProductId] but I don't know how to write it to connect the SQL and have a result.

Comment: I'm sorry but your question is not very clear. I'm not able to bridge the gap between the screenshots you pasted and the text in your post. What is the table in the first two screenshots? I can already see a Product name in your last screenshot so what is the problem?

Comment: What columns do you have available in table Upgrade? You should substitute UpgradeProductId for something like UpgradeProductName in the result.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question correctly.

The easy way to display the ProductName for your UpgradeProductId would be a SELECT statement for the column.
The statement would look like that:

```
    SELECT UpgradeId, Productname, (SELECT Product.ProductName FROM Product WHERE Product.ProductId = Upgrade.UpgradeProductId), UpgradeDate, UpgradeDetail
    FROM Upgrade
    INNER JOIN Product ON Upgrade.ProductId = Product.ProductId
    INNER JOIN RepairMan ON Upgrade.RepairManId = RepairMan.RepairManId
    WHERE Upgrade.RepairManId = '$RepairManId'
    ORDER BY UpgradeId ASC
```

However I guess, that this is not the most efficient solution.

To do the same with joins, you have to use aliases for your joined tables. It would look like this:

```
    SELECT UpgradeId, P1.Productname, P2.Productname, UpgradeDate, UpgradeDetail
    FROM Upgrade
    INNER JOIN Product AS P1 ON Upgrade.ProductId = P1.ProductId
    INNER JOIN Product AS P2 ON Upgrade.UpgradeProductId = P2.ProductId
    INNER JOIN RepairMan ON Upgrade.RepairManId = RepairMan.RepairManId
    WHERE Upgrade.RepairManId = '$RepairManId'
    ORDER BY UpgradeId ASC
```

Another thing besides that. I don't know exactly which SQL you are using, but be sure to add either ASC or DESC to your ORDER command. Without this addition, some types of SQL tend to not order as you intended.

Comment: I'll try it now and let you know if it work, Thank you for the help :)